# How to fix this springboot ErrorPageFilter error?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

It's a simple web application use external tomcat-9.0.56 and spring 5.3, springboot 2.5.5 and up, which works on windows 10 but not on ubuntu 18. It always display 404 because of the ErrorFilterPage.
The tomcat used Context to point to the folder where the webapp was located at, also virtual host in apache 000-default.conf
I've tried set setRegisterErrorPageFilter(false); or in the application.properties as well as inject @Bean FilterRegistrationBean disableSpringBootErrorFilter with/without return new ErrorPageFilter(); in @Bean public ErrorPageFilter errorPageFilter(), no success.

I feel despair at such a framework that can not deploy to Ubuntu with delays and disappointment that cause me a lot.

It's just a simple hello: http://localhost:8080/home:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BiJ4-E0nPjuh1YxREpOcwN4AlzdSe3Pu/view?usp=sharing

How to fix it?!

Comment: How have you identified that the error page filter is the cause of your problem? Perhaps you can share some more information about the problem and the suspected cause. It will make it easier for someone to try to help you.

Comment: I tried everything and remote debug it step by step, changed locations of resources, redo libraries, versions. In the debugging I saw the path resolved by springboot and returned too early from the ErrorPageFilter vs when I step into it with the one running on windows, the response is different with same version of tomcat/springboot/library/war. I would know better if I can disable it, but it's still there. @AndyWilkinson

Comment: I reproduce it here with source code: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17S2K3Ez8HW-xWrExu-nTECaR-uRIf5Cx @AndyWilkinson

Comment: @MoRep: please look into your application's logs (or Tomcat's logs if you are using an external Tomcat) and add them to your questions. Answers to questions are supposed to be useful to other users in the future, while your link to Google Drive will certainly become invalid.

Comment: External on Ubuntu, also tried RestController that returns ModelAndView, still not finding the jsp. @Piotr P. Karwasz

Comment: Is there a simple error such as [ or ] somewhere or root context since my tomcat pointed to the project folder not webapps ? @Piotr P. Karwasz

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in your `application.properties` file where you have configured `spring.mvc.view.prefix`. The value has a trailing space. It is `/WEB-INF/views/`  and should be `/WEB-INF/views/`. With this change in place, the `/hello` endpoint works:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/hello

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>SAMPLE</title>
</head>
<body>
HELLO SPRING!
</body>
</html>%
```

[Spring Boot intentionally does not trim whitespace from property values](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4106) as there's no way for it to know whether or not the whitespace is intentional.

Comment: I have it in ubuntu, forget it when reproduce it, it doesn't make any difference with or without it that I tried it long ago and struggling for a month till this day. Is it possible to take out the ErrorPageFilter since Bean or setEnabled(false) not working. @AndyWilkinson.

Comment: could tell the errorpagefilter$ErrorWrapperResponse is there at the filter chain before view resolver. Near the end, it says page not found by dispatchservlet in nohandlerfound method, then send the 404 error. But it runs on windows when uses localhost:8080, also able to return a string for RestController or ResponseBody. @AndyWilkinson